# Basic Authorisation with back slash "\" in username using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, basic-authentication

I have to use basic authorisation in my https request. I am using the following code :

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"p5\test", @"password"];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64String];
NSDictionary *data=@{@"Authorization":authValue};
```

But it always giving unauthorized 401 error. I have doubt might be username with backslash creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure NSString still uses the same special characters as C string. Try just adding and extra backslash to tur the \t (tab) into a \ (backslash)